# Elastic search _count queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question how to build more complex count queries with elastic search using the GET _count endpoint.

Currently I send the following request

```
https://address.com/elasticsearch/_count?q=tag:myTag
```

This works fine, however I want to add another parameter E.g.

```
https://address.com/elasticsearch/_count?q=tag:myTag&parameter:myParameter
```

Is this possible to do? Cannot find multiple parameters in the elastic search documentation. Also this needs to be possible to execute using a curl command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by concatenating the criteria using the `AND` keyword, i.e.

```
tag:myTag AND parameter:myParameter
```

So if you URL-encode the space characters, the full URL would look like this:

```
https://address.com/elasticsearch/_count?q=tag:myTag%20AND%20parameter:myParameter
```

Comment: Thx, you saved my day!